# JavaFX mp3 playback Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, mp3, javafx

I am trying to play mp3 file in java program using javafx. I installed dependencies `libavcodec53` and `libavformat53` [mentioned here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2.htm). I used following code

`public void play(String path_to_song){
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        String song = new File(path_to_song).toURI().toString();
        Media audio =null;
        audio = new Media(song);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio);
        mediaPlayer.play();
}`

But I still got error `"Error media audio format unsupported"`

`Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported" : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:125)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:383)
    at playback.Player.play(Player.java:39)
    at engine.Execute.main(Execute.java:15)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MediaUtils.nativeError(MediaUtils.java:331)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.init(GSTMedia.java:50)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.<init>(GSTMedia.java:33)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.<init>(GSTMediaPlayer.java:39)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform.prerollMediaPlayer(GSTPlatform.java:100)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager.createMediaPlayer(PlatformManager.java:173)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:264)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:139)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:431)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading Java. It was bug in current version back than.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848752/javafx-mp3-playback-ubuntu-14-04